# jQuery moving element highlights table cells in Firefox

Tags: jquery, highlighting, mousedown

I have the following code:

```
// Drag Event
var _isMoving = false;
$("body").on("mousedown", ".k-event", function () {
    _isMoving = true;
});

// This is here because otherwise the mouse will try and select the grid and looks really ugly
$("body").mousemove(function (e) {
    if (_isMoving)
        e.preventDefault();
});

$("body").mouseup(function () {
    _isMoving = false;
});
```

On Chrome, this works great.

However, on Firefox, when I try and move the mouse with the mouse button depressed, it still wants to highlight the table cells (as if I were trying to copy/paste something).  How can I tell Firefox not to try and highlight anything?

Comment: $("body").on("mousedown", ".k-event", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); _isMoving = true;
}

Comment: That did the trick.  Post as an answer and I'll give credit.

Comment: (OT) P.S. I believe you're aware that you're missing `);` twice! :) just noticing and pointing out for novice programmers that might look at your code ;)

Comment: Modified code to fix those errors.  Nice catch, Roko!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Firefox** you should prevent the event on the `mousedown` event as well:

```
$("body").on("mousedown", ".k-event", function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  _isMoving = true; 
}
```